# Search databases for table with values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008. My question is, is it possible, given a table name, to construct a query that returns a list of databases that contain that table WITH values (meaning it is not empty)?

For example, I have a table called `tbl_Name`. I have 100 databases, and in 90 of them `tbl_Name` is empty. Can I get a list of the 10 databases where `tbl_Name` has values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a cursor, and the stored procedure `sp_msforeachdb`.

`sp_msforeachdb` is, as the name suggests, a proc that runs something for each database.  You can use this to list all db's with a given table name:

```
sp_msforeachdb 'SELECT "?" AS db from [?].sys.tables WHERE name = ''tbl_Name'''
```

Inserting those records into a temp table makes it easy to iterate over in a cursor:

```
DROP TABLE #db_List
DROP TABLE #Not_Empty
GO
CREATE TABLE #db_List (db VARCHAR(MAX))
CREATE TABLE #Not_Empty (db VARCHAR(MAX))
GO
sp_msforeachdb 'INSERT INTO #db_List SELECT "?" AS db from [?].sys.tables WHERE name = ''tbl_Name'''
GO

SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @Iterator varchar(MAX)
       ,@strSQL varchar(MAX) 
DECLARE xyz CURSOR
FOR
    --Select stuff to iterate over
    SELECT *
    FROM #db_List
OPEN xyz 
FETCH NEXT FROM xyz 
INTO @Iterator 
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
--Do stuff
SET @strSQL = 'INSERT INTO #Not_Empty              
               SELECT '''+@Iterator+'''
               WHERE EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM '+@Iterator+'..tbl_Name)
               '
Exec (@strSQL)
    FETCH NEXT FROM xyz 
    INTO @Iterator 
END
CLOSE xyz 
DEALLOCATE xyz 
GO
SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick summary:

Start in master DB select from **sys.databases**, get all the DB's, **cursor** thru each one (USE the DB).  Use **EXEC( sqlStatement )** to perform your command etc...

**Now that you're in the DB** (Each DB has a table named sys.objects, so your goal from the above paragraph is to simply issue a command like **EXEC(USE dbName**)  ) list through the list of tables, select from **sys.objects**, look for object types of 'U' (user table).  Get the name, construct your SELECT * FROM  INTO #yourTemp WHERE blah blah blah  insert your results in a #temp table you created at the very beginning..  Issue the SQL via **EXEC()**